# Delphi REST Request async

Tags: delphi

I have built the backend (with WebBroker) and it has some APIs. So in the client I am going to use the REST components to get the json and parse it. This is an example:

```
procedure TForm1.ButtonCreateClick(Sender: TObject);
begin

 //rreqTodoCreate is a TRESTRequest component!

 rreqTodoCreate.Params[0].Value := EditTitle.Text;
 rreqTodoCreate.Params[1].Value := EditCategory.Text;

 rreqTodoCreate.ExecuteAsync(procedure
                             begin
                              ResponseEdit.Text := rrespToDo.Content;
                             end);

end;
```

I am using the `ExecuteAsync` as the docwiki suggests also because I am on mobile and I don't want the UI to freeze! I have read that `ExecuteAsync` runs on a separate thread and so I have a doubt.

Is the code I have written thread-safe? Or in other words: should I use Queue or Synchronize when I update the text of a component in the main form?

Comment: Er, UI access has to happen on the UI thread doesn't it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes! So I guess that it's better if I call TThread.Queue

Answer (score 6):

Per the [`TRESTRequest.ExecuteAsync()` documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.ExecuteAsync):

> Parameters
>
> This method defines the following parameters:
>
> - `ACompletionHandler` -- Specifies an anonymous method to run after completing the request execution.
> - **`ASynchronized` -- When True, specifies that the method set in `ACompletionHandler` runs in the main thread context. When False, `ACompletionHandler` runs in the execution thread context.**
> - `AFreeThread` - When True, the execution thread is freed after completing the request execution.

The `ASynchronized` parameter is `True` by default:

```
function ExecuteAsync(
  ACompletionHandler: TCompletionHandler = nil;
  ASynchronized: Boolean = True;  // <--
  AFreeThread: Boolean = True;
  ACompletionHandlerWithError: TCompletionHandlerWithError = nil): TRESTExecutionThread;
```

So, the code you have shown is perfectly fine as-is, the assignment of the `ResponseEdit.Text` is thread-safe.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I also think that this is better:

```
rreqTodoCreate.ExecuteAsync(procedure
                            begin
                              TThread.Queue(procedure 
                                            begin
                                              ResponseEdit.BeginUpdate;
                                              ResponseEdit.Text := rrespToDo.Content;
                                              ResponseEdit.EndUpdate;
                                            end;   
                            end);
```

Explanation:

1. TThread.Queue executes the anonymous method in the main thread
2. BeginUpdate and EndUpdate freeze the UI and speed up the update of form

Comment: I think it's better, but a bit of explanation might be useful, especially about why you added BeginUpdate and EndUpdate.

Comment: @GolezTrol I have updated my answer with an explanation :)

Comment: The `ExecuteAsync()` completion handlering is synchronized by default, so the extra call to `TThread.Queue()` is actually redundant.  Also, calling `(Begin|End)Update()` is not very beneficial when you are only updating one thing. They should be used when updating multiple things at one time.